# How do we correctly exclude an {'1} value from a cover group?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I got the following covergroup implemented:

```
covergroup my_covergroup_cg  (input string name);
      enable_reg_cp : coverpoint enabled_reg[PARAM1-1:0] {
         illegal_bins no_enable = {0};
      }
      feature_active_reg_cp : coverpoint feature_active_reg_mask[PARAM2-1:0] { // Interested in covering a PARAM2-width chunk of a 32-bit feature_active_reg
         illegal_bins all_features_active = {'1}; // We must not activate all features (1 bit = 1 feature active)
      }      
      my_covergroup_cross : cross enable_reg_cp , feature_active_reg_cp {
         illegal_bins il0 = (binsof (enable_reg_cp) intersect {0});
         illegal_bins il1 = (binsof (feature_active_reg_cp) intersect {'1});
      }
   endgroup : my_covergroup_cg
```

Upon execution, the "il1" illegal bin of my cross gets hit with a value  "0x1" of the 
feature_active_reg_mask[PARAM2-1:0] - which is completly legal and does not match the {'1} (equivalent to ..111111 : all ones).

Is there a particular issue of how these {'1} are treated in the "binsof" scope ?

Comment: Please note that PARAM2 is absolutely greater than 1.

Comment: Dont remember enough about covergroups to know for sure, but did you try the replication operator instead? (`{$bits(feature_active_reg_cp){1'b1}}`) My guess would be that the right side of an `intersect` statement is "self-determined" so `'1` takes on a width of 1 (see LRM 2012; 5.7.1). (Putting this as a comment as Im really not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share my workaround for knowledge share:
I have decided to go with using `localparam` semantic. As it appears the issue is related to the tool interpreting the `{'1}`.
I did the following:

```
localparam all_ones = {PARAM2{1'b1}};
covergroup my_covergroup_cg  (input string name);
      enable_reg_c .... // rest of code
```

and I passed the alias into my `illegal_bins`

```
illegal_bins il1 = (binsof (feature_active_reg_cp) intersect {all_ones});
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

This is most likley a tool issue. According to section 19.5.7 Value resolution in the 1800-20167 LRM, All bin expression get evaluated in the context of the coverpoint type. You can use `[$:$]` as an alternative that represents the largest possible value.

BUT... the `illegal_bins` in the `cross` is unnecessary because only the included bins of a coverpoint get crossed. AND... one you define an explicit set of bins, there are no implicitly defined bins, so you should write this as

```
covergroup my_covergroup_cg  (input string name);
      enable_reg_cp : coverpoint enabled_reg[PARAM1-1:0] {
         bins enable[] = {[1:$]}; // will be split into N bins according to auto_bins_max
      }
      feature_active_reg_cp : coverpoint feature_active_reg_mask[PARAM2-1:0] { // Interested in covering a PARAM2-width chunk of a 32-bit feature_active_reg
         bins some_features_active = {[0:$]}; 
         ignore_bins all_features_active = {[$:$]}; // We must not activate all features (1 bit = 1 feature active)
      }      
      my_covergroup_cross : cross enable_reg_cp , feature_active_reg_cp;
   endgroup : my_covergroup_cg
```

In the 2<sup>nd</sup> coverpoint, the $ value overlaps the two bin specifications, but the `ignore_bins` overrides that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have alrady used the `[$:$] ` and noticed that the tool considers it as a range andnot a maximum value, thus it illegalize all possible values the coverpoint can get.